# How to change the starting day of this week's calendar?

Tags: php, calendar

im trying to implement a calendar in my website, im using code from: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/3889-free-form-calendar-application/ The main code is in the  second post. But the thing is that the week starts on sunday and i need to change it to monday and i can't  figure out how to do that. A little help is needed!:)

Comment: Ask the developer to add it as an option, if it's not one already.

Comment: This calendar is created few years ago it seems to me that this project is not developing anymore.

Comment: Perhaps, then, it's not the best choice. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used that class before, but reading the source code I see this line:

```
/* table headings */
$headings = array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
```

initializing the variable `headings` whose contents are not modified in the whole program, and they are simply printed to the HTML string (variable `calendar`) with an `implode`.

This class also lacks a parameter for the constructor to tell it that the user needs the output with Monday (or any other day) as the first day of the week...

If you want to modify this class in order to implement that functionality, you should do:

- For the heading cells: make your changes around the line where the `implode` over the `headings` variable is done.
- For the remaining cells: analyze carefully the variable `running_day`.
- Also do not forget that it is nice to have this behaviour set by a variable given as parameter to the constructor of the class.